# Tool to Verify Format Strings in C/C++ source

Tags: c++, c

I have updated the contents and arguments of printf style format strings in a large C/C++ code base. The code compiles ok but it is hard to actually get those errors and verify that my changes were right.

Is there a tool/compiler option that can validate the format strings for having the right no. of arguments. It would be nice if it doesn't try to compile the whole thing because  then the dependencies etc must be present in the expected places.

I could write a quick script but I could reuse something that already exists and handles the corner cases too.

Something like :-

```
% cat test.c

#include <iostream>
#include "dependency2.h"
int main()
{
    function2(log, "You encountered a common error %s: %d", error)
}

% somenicetool test.c

5: too few arguments
```

I tried clang but the first error it gives is this :-

```
% clang -fsyntax-only test.c

#include "dependency2.h"
         ^
file not found
1 error generated
```

Comment: It is mostly C++ with some C. Changing to streams would be a mega task unlikely to be taken up.

Comment: @Himanshu: I presume `<dependency.h>` is a filler for a real header file? Either way, the error clang has given you must be easily solvable right? :)

Comment: Just checked that. If I fix those errors clang does seem to work ok. How about code meant for visual c++ compiler. Do we have an option there as well.

Comment: Apparently clang is out because it doesn't check nonprintf functions which are just what I have.

Comment: the error message does not match the source you posted. you should consider fixing that :)

Comment: oh, and another thing. can you show us the code of function2?

Comment: It is a variant of printf writing to log pointed to by the first argument and some addnl info in second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If using `gcc` and `--Wformat`, and you have your own functions, you will need to use the `__attribute__(format, printf, format_argno, first_var_arg)` after the function.

For example:

```
void log_print(FILE *logfile, int level, const char *format, ...)
   __attribute__(format, printf, 3, 4);
```

gcc also understands "scanf", "strfmon" and "strftime" format specifications, just replace "printf" with whatever suits your function.

Comment: This worked nicely for the llvm warnings. I wonder if there is something for vc++ as well. Thankx.

Comment: I don't think visual studio has this particular feature - although it's been a long time since I last used VS - two, maybe three years, and that was C++ using cout and co.

Answer (score 5):

With gcc, you can use the `--Wformat` option:

> Check calls to printf and scanf, etc., to make sure that the arguments
>   supplied have types appropriate to the format string specified, and
>   that the conversions specified in the format string make sense. This
>   includes standard functions, and others specified by format attributes
>   (see Function Attributes), in the printf, scanf, strftime and strfmon
>   (an X/Open extension, not in the C standard) families (or other
>   target-specific families).

See [the gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat-272) for more details.

Edit: Looking at this more carefully, it looks like you want to check calls to your own functions which possibly forward the calls to printf and friends. You probably have to decorate your function with the [`format` function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-Wformat-2586) in order to get the warnings from gcc.

Answer (score 1):

I think [CPPCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) picks up those, and plenty, plenty more...

**Edit:** Hmm. I have a feeling it only works for standard library functions, and doesn't understand the 'Function Attributes' you can use to tell GCC that your 'own' functions use format strings.

Comment: Yes cppcheck is not the one. Tried with --enable=all but didn't get them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember about the `__attribute__ ((format (printf, n, m)))` solution: if your function is a non-static member method of a class, you have to add 1 to both n and m since it's compiled as a simple function with the **this** pointer as the actual first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cppcheck can do it! [See manual, section "3.1.4 Format string".](https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/reference-cfg-format.pdf)

Also, [ReSharper can do it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__String_Formatting_Methods.html#custom).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32721086)